# SDL_RenderPresent is writing over the previous frame

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, c, sdl2

Whenever I call `SDL_RenderPresent`, the previous frame is replaced with black before the new frame is displayed. It's almost like when I call `SDL_RenderPresent(renderer)`, it automatically calls `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255)` and then`SDL_RenderClear(renderer)`.

I want to keep the previous frame because only 100 pixels are changed per frame. How do I prevent it from writing over the previous frame?

Here's an example:

```
// Error checking removed for clarity
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", 0, 0, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

// after some other, non-SDL related stuff, I run this code:
SDL_Rect a = {
    .x = 0,
    .y = 0,
    .w = 100,
    .h = 100
};
SDL_Rect b = {
    .x = 200,
    .y = 0,
    .w = 100,
    .h = 100
};

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &a);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
// A red outline of a square is displayed on a white background
SDL_Delay(2500);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &b);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
// A green outline of a square is displayed on a black background.
// The red outline is gone.
SDL_Delay(2500);
```

How do I prevent SDL_RenderPresent from painting over the previous frame with black? Why is it doing that even though I'm not telling it to clear between the presents?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent "*The backbuffer should be considered invalidated after each present; do not assume that previous contents will exist between frames*" - this is actually normal and desirable behaviour when drawing because graphics cards can optimize better if they don't have to preserve the previous frame.  Even if only a few pixels change it's a false optimization and you should always just redraw the full scene each frame.

Answer (score 3):

To get past this, you might be able to use a texture buffer which you render to **before** rendering to the window. This is accomplished with creating a texture with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET`, and using `SDL_SetRenderTarget`.

A link with an example can be found here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/143394/95877

Note: I do not know the intricacies of this, and the wording does not state this "backbuffer" only applies to a window, but since `SDL_RenderClear` only clears the current rendering target with the current color, if you do not call this on a texture, I see no reason the texture itself would ever be invalidated, as it is a texture of course.